# How to make exe file use yolov

Tags: yolov5

I make yolov5 detect program and it is perfectly run in pycharm.

However, when i make exe file by pyinstaller, it make error like attached image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtsKU.jpg)

How to fix this error? I need make exe file

(https://github.com/jongkwonwon/LGE_DX3/blob/main/UI/UI_ver10_Layout.py)

Comment: somewhere it is replacing / with wierd characters, make sure to chack all paths for spüeelling and files for encoding